# How to Add Preview Thumbnails in swift AV player

Tags: swift, video, avplayer

I have an AV player which streams video from url, I want to show thumbnail of video while dragging slider in forward or backward direction(like feature in youtube). can you explain how to add this feature using swift.

LIKE THIS

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9ngVJbhTDvWABBt49T-QrSfA354bERa/view

Answer (score 1):

If your playlist files already support the EXT-X-IMAGE-STREAM-INF tag and you are using the standard player controller (AVPlayerViewController) then you will have that feature for free. But if you are using customized UI for your player or your playlist doesn't support that tag, you have to build that feature by your self. It's possible because all you have to do is just display correct frames on top of the AVPlayer layer in proper positions.

Comment: Thanks Cong, You have a any demo projects to refer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have

Answer (score -3):

```
if fileUrl.containsVideo {
                let generateThumbnail = (try? AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset).copyCGImage(at: .init(seconds: 30, preferredTimescale: 60), actualTime: nil)) ?? UIImage(systemName: "music.note")?.cgImage!
                    img = UIImage(cgImage: generateThumbnail!)
                    itemtitle = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
                }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation too.